# Struggling with recursive code to bisection search a string

Tags: python, bisection

So I'm taking a python class online. I would like help spotting the differences between my code and the correct answer code. I didn't annotate mine but the answer is annotated and every thing you need should be there to figure out what I'm trying to do. I wrote my answer independently at first and it turns out to be pretty similar to the correct answer code given by the class. However, my code keeps returning the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "submission.py", line 11, in isIn
    middle = aStr[midIndex]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is my code

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    # Your code here
    midIndex = len(aStr)//2 
    middle = aStr[midIndex]

    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return False
    if len(aStr) == 1 or char == middle:
        return True
    else:
        if char > middle:
            return isIn(char,aStr[:middle])
        else:
            return isIn(char,aStr[middle +1:])
```

here is the correct answer given to me by the class:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
   '''
   char: a single character
   aStr: an alphabetized string

   returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
   '''
   # Base case: If aStr is empty, we did not find the char.
   if aStr == '':
      return False

   # Base case: if aStr is of length 1, just see if the chars are equal
   if len(aStr) == 1:
      return aStr == char

   # Base case: See if the character in the middle of aStr equals the 
   #   test character 
   midIndex = len(aStr)//2
   midChar = aStr[midIndex]
   if char == midChar:
      # We found the character!
      return True

   # Recursive case: If the test character is smaller than the middle 
   #  character, recursively search on the first half of aStr
   elif char < midChar:
      return isIn(char, aStr[:midIndex])

   # Otherwise the test character is larger than the middle character,
   #  so recursively search on the last half of aStr
   else:
      return isIn(char, aStr[midIndex+1:])
```

`midIndex` for my code is `middle_nummber` and `midChar` for my code is just `middle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version has 4 errors; two in handling the edge cases, and the other two in determining what half to search in.

Your code isn't handling the 'empty string' case correctly. For a string of length 0, `midIndex` will be `0`, but `aStr[0]` won't exist.

This is why the annotated answer *starts* with

```
if aStr == '':
    return False
```

If the input is empty, you can't find the searched-for string. You do test for that case, but you do it too late. This is what causes the traceback you shared:

```
>>> aStr = ''
>>> midIndex = len(aStr)//2
>>> midIndex
0
>>> aStr[midIndex]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Next, you are handling the `len(aStr) == 1` edge-case wrong too. Your test is:

```
if len(aStr) == 1 or char == middle:
    return True
```

If `aStr` is set to `'z'`, then `len(aStr)` is true, and it doesn't matter what `char` is set to. So `aStr = 'z';`char = 'a'`, will produce`True` from your function, which is clearly not correct:

```
>>> aStr = 'z'
>>> char = 'a'
>>> middle = 'z'
>>> len(aStr) == 1 or char == middle
True
```

The correct answer instead simply tests if `aStr == char` is true for the length-is-1 case; I'd stick to that, or at least replace `or` with `and`:

```
>>> len(aStr) == 1 and char == middle
False
>>> char = 'z'
>>> len(aStr) == 1 and char == middle
True
```

Your next error is in what half you search in. You test:

```
if char > middle:
```

so the searched for character is *greater* than the mid-point. You want to search in the second, upper half of your sorted input string. Instead, your version searches in the *opposite*, lower half:

```
if char > middle:
    return isIn(char,aStr[:middle])  # slicing up to the middle
```

Using digits instead of letters to illustrate this better, the input string `'12345'` has a midpoint `'3'`, so if `char` is either `'4'` or `'5'`, you want to find it in the second half.

Your 4th and last error is in that `aStr[:middle]` expression. `middle` is a single character, not an integer index. You want to use `midIndex`:

```
if char > middle:
    return isIn(char, aStr[:midIndex])
else:
    return isIn(char, aStr[midIndex + 1:])
```